# Windows Vista shutting down while configuring updates

Tags: windows-vista, shutdown, windows-update

Im currently working on a PC (running Windows Vista) that keeps shutting down while configuring 3/3 updates after logon (`Configuring 3/3 updates, 0%.`), but then after a couple of seconds, the computer just shuts down.

So my question, how can I stop Vista from trying to install updates from a command prompt (as I have access via a repair disk)?

Comment: I would run "sfc /scannow` to verify the system image intrigity isn't a problem.

Comment: I've tried it, doesn't work. I get 'There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete. Restart Windows and run sfc again', but unfortunately i can't reboot because of the update problem. :|

Comment: if the scan detected a problem then you have a serious problem.  You should be able to shutdwon without installing the update though.

Comment: Are you able to log in to safe mode? Typically windows creates a restore point before installing updates. The best thing you can do is to gain access and restore to said point.

Comment: @ Ramhound, The scan doesn't run, it gave the above error.

Comment: @Will.Beninger, Unfortunately the system restore can't find any previous restore points, and even in safe mode windows still tries to configure updates, so it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancel Pending updates:

1. Boot from install media (Windows Vista or 7 install disk should be fine)
2. Select "Command Prompt" from the recovery choices.
3. At the command prompt change your directory to `C:\Windows\WinSxS`
4. Type: **del pending.xml**
5. Exit and reboot.

If it's not already, install [KB937287](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15287) by itself.

After that's done install other/remaining updates one at a time. Once all others are done, install any Service Packs that may be waiting in the update queue.

Comment: How do i change the cmd directory?

Comment: `cd ..` to go up one and `cd thatdirectory` to go into a directory. `dir` to view the files in a directory.

Comment: I've tried using, cd C:\Windows\WinSxS , But that still doesn't work, it's still set at X:\Sources>

Comment: Change to the C: drive first (type `c:`), or use CD's `/d` option (`cd /d c:\windows\winsxs`). Maybe [check this out](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/13195.aspx) for a quick command line/DOS primer.